# Can I do some custom action when Biztalk retry to send the message to send port?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

I know, that BizTalk retries to send the message again, if message sending failed due to some reason.

Can I call some C# method when BizTalk retry action happen?

If yes then, how?

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve exactly? I feel you want to do something specifically, only during retries.
Have you tried using the Backup Transport of a send port?

Comment: I just want to send some email to desired users whenever biztalk reattempts to send the message ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot call a method when the port is retrying. However, you can disable the retry functionality and mimic the same behavior in a BizTalk orchestration. You would need to implement `Delivery Notification` on your logical port in your BizTalk orchestration. This way, when delivery fails, you can implement your custom code when retrying.

More info on delivery notification can be found here: 
http://kentweare.blogspot.be/2007/11/biztalk-delivery-notification.html

You can even customize your own retry mechanism for any given amount of tries with any given amount of delay.

So in short: no built-in functionality, you would need to do the same, which is trivial using Delivery Notification.